# Rehosted Workflow Designer default imported namespaces

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, rehosting, workflow-rehosting

I'm trying to rehost the WF4 Workflow Designer. In the "Imports" tab, I'd like to have some namespaces imported by default. It looks like this:

[Imported namespaces http://imageshack.us/m/850/5383/imports.png](http://imageshack.us/m/850/5383/imports.png)

After a lot of research, I figured out that if you look at

```
workflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<ImportedNamespaceContextItem>().ImportedNamespaces
```

you'll get to see things that are already imported. However, adding a namespace manually to this collection does not seem to have any effect. My question, therefore, is: How do I add imported namespaces to this list the right way? Or, how do I get the context to refresh using my manually added namespace imports?

---

**Additional information to the solution below**:

In order to solve this, I created my desired "clean slate" activity XAML file, added it to my project, set its *Build Action* to *Embedded Resource* and its *Custom Tool* to empty string.

Then, in the code that initializes my WorkflowDesigner, I do the following:

```
_Wd = new WorkflowDesigner();

_Wd.Load(
    XamlServices.Load(
        ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(
            new XamlXmlReader(
                Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( "WpfApplication1.New.xaml" )
            )
        )
    ) as ActivityBuilder
);
```

Now my work flow has all the desirable namespaces imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is by not starting with a completely empty workflow but creating an empty template with the required imports. Add something like:

```
 xmlns:si="clr-namespace:System.IO;assembly=mscorlib"
```

to the root activity in the XAML file to import System.IO

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing this before you posted your solution. Still, I'll give you the "accepted answer checkmark" because your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution solves a different problem with rehosting stream based activities as well and there is no proposed solution that I could find, so I post this here.

The **Symptom** is that you get a modal dialog in your designer host, that states a null reference exception in System.Activities.Presentation.View.ImportDesigner.OnContextChanged(),
if you loaded an activity with

```
ActivityXamlServices.Load(aStream)  // wrong way!
```

**Cause:** In

```
OnContextChanged() // of class ImportDesigner
```

in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities.Presentation/System.Activities.Presentation/System/Activities/Presentation/View/ImportDesigner.xaml.cs,1d24713ba95e69c5 accessing the .Collection of the "Imports" property raises the null pointer exception. Probably because no information on imported namespaces got loaded.

**Solution:** Use the Activity

```
ab.Implementation // of the ActivityBuilder ab
```

from Alex' post and .Load() it into the WorkflowDesigner instance.

**Full code snippet:**

```
public static Activity LoadActivityFrom(FileInfo xaml)
{
  using (var rd = xaml.OpenRead())
  using (var xr = new System.Xaml.XamlXmlReader(rd))
  using (var br = System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(xr))
  {
    var ab = System.Xaml.XamlServices.Load(br) as System.Activities.ActivityBuilder;
    return ab.Implementation;
  }
}
```